# Adding a command at the beginning of every line using bash command

Tags: regex, bash, shell

How can I a command at the beginning of every line example -

My file contains following text -

```
abc
efg
hij
```

So I want to add this `sed -n '/^<<</,/^>>>/p'` i.e.

```
sed -n '/^<<</,/^>>>/p' abc
sed -n '/^<<</,/^>>>/p' efg
sed -n '/^<<</,/^>>>/p' hij
```

I tried to run this command

`sed -i 's/^/sed -n '/^<<</,/^>>>/p'' test.txt` but it did not work.

Can someone help here ?

Comment: try this one : `sed -i "s#^#sed \-n \'/\<\<\</\\,/\^\>\>\>/p\' #" test.txt`

Comment: Thanks @User123 this works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk for that:

```
$ cat test 
abc
def
ghi
$ awk '{print "sed -n \x27/^<</,/^>>/p\x27 " $0}' test
sed -n '/^<</,/^>>/p' abc
sed -n '/^<</,/^>>/p' def
sed -n '/^<</,/^>>/p' ghi
```

I am pretty sure that using `'` in print can be done with better style then `\x27`, but I do not have a good idea for that right now.

Comment: Thanks @Szczerba this works good but I will go with sed -i "s#^#sed \-n \'/\<\<\</\\,/\^\>\>\>/p\' #" test.txt which User123 recommended as this would save me a step of creating a new file.